# Develop mobile apps in angular framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mobile

*Hi Friends,*

I am learning angular framework. The official Angular website says one platform for mobile and web. But I couldn't see any official docs or tutorials for mobile UI. Which means we can launch angular apps in mobile using a web browser? or is there any official way (without third party jars) to create mobile apps in angular? Could anyone please explain about this.

*Thanks*

*Manivannan*

Comment: Please be specific what version of angular are you learning? You might want take a look on Ionic framework which is using Angular for mobile applications.

Comment: hi Observer. I am learning angular 5. But I guess Iconic framework is a third party framework which is using angularjs. But why cant we directly use angular mobile ui instead of using iconic

Comment: Look at NativeScript "https://www.nativescript.org/" if you want to build native apps using angular5 or if you want just a web app you can look into "http://mobileangularui.com/docs/"

Comment: Thanks for the response. Nativescript means no typescript? And  the mobileangularui website uses angularjs.  Can't we use pure angular components to develop mobile apps in official way? Why angular team  does not have official docs?